# Elixir + Phoenix: How to use Agent as a store?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a chat app where both parties have to press "accept" before they enter a chat. The sequence goes like this:

1. Party A joins the channel. `Agent` will `start_link` with party
   A's email address as the key
2. Party B joins the channel. `Agent`
   will `start_link` with party B's email address as the key
3. Party A
   presses accept. If B has yet to accept (Agent., `Agent` will store `Party
   A's email -> Party B's email -> true`, otherwise send a message to
   party B that party A has also accepted.
4. Party B presses accept.
   If A has yet to accept, `Agent` will store `Party A's email -> Party
   B's email -> true`, otherwise send a message to party A that party B
   has also accepted.

I'm running into an error right now where it doesn't seem like the

```
2017-03-01T14:02:40.434791+00:00 app[web.1]: 14:02:40.433 [error] GenServer #PID<0.1743.0> terminating
2017-03-01T14:02:40.434793+00:00 app[web.1]: ** (stop) exited in: GenServer.call(:"dhdjsjsjs@plabs.com", {:get, #Function<1.108716101/1 in VideoChat.CallChannel.handle_in/3>}, 5000)
2017-03-01T14:02:40.434794+00:00 app[web.1]:     ** (EXIT) no process
2017-03-01T14:02:40.434795+00:00 app[web.1]:     (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:596: GenServer.call/3
2017-03-01T14:02:40.434795+00:00 app[web.1]:     (video_chat) web/channels/call_channel.ex:152: VideoChat.CallChannel.handle_in/3
2017-03-01T14:02:40.434796+00:00 app[web.1]:     (phoenix) lib/phoenix/channel/server.ex:226: anonymous fn/4 in Phoenix.Channel.Server.handle_info/2
2017-03-01T14:02:40.434797+00:00 app[web.1]:     (stdlib) gen_server.erl:615: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
2017-03-01T14:02:40.434798+00:00 app[web.1]:     (stdlib) gen_server.erl:681: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
2017-03-01T14:02:40.434798+00:00 app[web.1]:     (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Here is my channel:

```
  def join("user_pool:" <> email, %{ "app" => app }, socket) do
    Logger.info "PRODUCTION user_pool email: #{email}, app: #{app}"
    socket = assign(socket, :email, email)
    socket = assign(socket, :app, app)

    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: :"#{email}") # <---------------- should start link here
    {:ok, socket}
  end


  def handle_in("approve_match", %{ "matched_client_email" => matched_client_email }, socket) do
    Logger.info "approve_match"
    current_user_email = socket.assigns[:email]

    Agent.update :"#{current_user_email}", fn state ->
      Map.put(state, matched_client_email, true)
    end

    match_accepted = Agent.get(:"#{matched_client_email}", &(Map.get(&1, current_user_email))) # <----------- breaks here. this is line 152
    Logger.info "#{matched_client_email} has approved #{current_user_email}: #{match_accepted}"
    case match_accepted do
      true ->
        VideoChat.Endpoint.broadcast(
          "user_pool:#{matched_client_email}",
          "match_accepted",
          %{ matched_client_email: socket.assigns[:email] }
        )
        {:noreply, socket}
      _ ->
        Logger.info "2nd person has yet to approve"
        {:noreply, socket}
    end
  end
```

It doesn't seem to break when I run a test line in the console:

```
iex(20)> Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: :"blah")
{:ok, #PID<0.365.0>}
iex(21)> Agent.get(:"blah", &(Map.get(&1, "sdfs")))
nil
```

Am I just using `Agent` incorrectly?

Comment: You also likely should fix the title, since `Agent` is to be used as nothing but a store. Now it sounds a bit tautological.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a line that fails:

```
Agent.get(:"#{matched_client_email}" ...)
```

That happens because this `Agent` is not necessarily started. What you check in your test is different, to replicate the behaviour you should:

```
iex(20)> Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: :"blah")
{:ok, #PID<0.365.0>}
iex(21)> Agent.get(:"foo", &(Map.get(&1, "sdfs"))) # NOTE :foo
```

One might explicitly check if the target `Agent` was already started, or `try`/`catch` `Agent.get`.

Besides that, you spawn agents without being supervised; that might lead to unexpected problems when the `Agent` goes down for some reason: it will not be restarted (remaining down) and you’ll experience the behaviour as above.

I personally would go with one supervised `Agent`, holding everything using `email` as key. The value might be as complicated as you need, just map `email`⇒`%{}`.

Comment: Hi! How would I add a supervisor? Sorry I'm new to elixir

Comment: In [`Application.start/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#start/2) in the very top file of your app, as generated by phoenix, add a `worker`. There are examples commented out inside.

Comment: which file are you referring to?

Comment: The one that contains `use Application` line in it. If your project is named `MyApp`, it would be `lib/my_app.ex`.